# Concatenating Variables in different datasets

Tags: sas, concatenation, do-loops

I have multiple datasets with different columns. Let us suppose dataset 1 has col1,col2,col3 whereas datsets 2 as col1 and col2 only.

Now I want to combine all these columns with a "," (comma).I have created a macro that will combine all the columns(col1,col2,col3) with a comma. But if there are less number of columns in another dataset there will be extra comma that I do not want.

For example if I write a code total=catx(col1,col2,col3) the result will be 
1,2,

All i want is my result to be 1,2 with no extra commas

Kindly suggest me how to do this using a do loop.

**Code**

```
%macro xyz (data, data_1);
   proc sort data =a.&data.;
   by Type;
   where Type ne " ";
   run;

proc transpose data=a.&data. out=a.&data1.;
var string;
run;

data a.&data1.;
set a.&data1.;
total=catx(",",col1,col2,col3);
run; 
%mend;
%xyz(gold,gold1);
%xyz(silver,silver1);
```

**so if there are three variables in gol1 but 2 in silver1 on concatenating the total will give me a extra comma in the total variable which I do not require.I know because I have given a extra column(col3) in the catx statement so thats y it will give me extra comma but as I said different datasets different number of variables**

Comment: No, CATX accounts for missing values and even missing variables though you will get a message in the log.

Comment: @Reeza, So how do i remove that extra comma if there are less variables than the columns mentioned in my catx statement.I basically want to use a macro to do this for 100 datasets. Each dataset has different number of variables and if there are less number of variables i do not want a extra comma in my final concatenated variable

Comment: CatX doesn't include them in my tests. Post your code if you're having issues.

Comment: @Reeza..codde has been added. Thank you

Comment: Dynamically calculate the number of variables then. I'll post the code.

Comment: @Reeza.Thank you so much for posting the code and helping me out.Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
data a.&data1.;
set a.&data1.;
array col(3) col1-col3;
total=catx(",", of col(*));
run;
```

The answer depends on how you list the variables. If you use `OF` it accounts for the missing values, if you use the explicit list method, it doesn't.

Comment: Works, works, works!! Thank you so much @reeza. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Make sure the extra variable doesn't cause issues further on.

Comment: Yes, I will make sure of that

Answer (score 0):

Given your example I would use a name prefix list.

```
total=catx(',',OF COL:);
```

[SAS Variable Lists](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm)